# Redirecting after login with angular2-meteor

Tags: meteor, angular, meteor-accounts, angular-meteor, angular2-routing

I would like to use that simple UI pattern, when user is redirected to the dashboard after log in.

So if user is logout - he can see only a home page. After log in he is redirected to /dashboard.

How can I do that with angular2 routers and meteor accounts package?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the accounts-ui package doesn't appear to expose a lifecycle hook or any other obvious way to run extra code when the login and logout methods are triggered.

So this also isn't the most elegant solution, but it works—using angular2-meteor-accounts-ui (available on GitHub and NPM):

```
import { Component, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { MeteorComponent } from 'angular2-meteor';
import { InjectUser, LoginButtons } from 'angular2-meteor-accounts-ui';

import template from './app.component.html';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template,
  directives: [ LoginButtons, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ]
})
@InjectUser('user')
export class AppComponent extends MeteorComponent implements DoCheck {
  private isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
  private user: Meteor.User;

  constructor( private router: Router ) { super(); }

  ngDoCheck() {
    if (!this.isLoggedIn && !!this.user) {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
      if (this.router.url === '/') {
        this.router.navigate( ['/dashboard'] );
      }
    } else if (this.isLoggedIn && this.user === null) {
      this.isLoggedIn = false;
      if (this.router.url === '/dashboard') {
        this.router.navigate( ['/'] );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There's also a post on the Meteor forums describing a different solution, by not using an accounts-ui package and instead creating your own login() method, here:

https://forums.meteor.com/t/angular2-meteor-redirect-after-successful-login-for-custom-login-form/19312

Answer (score -1):

This might not be the most elegant solution, but I ended up using autorun to redirect the user after logging in.

```
$scope.autorun(() => {
  let currentUser = Meteor.user();
  if (currentUser)
    $state.go('home');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for advice, but isn't that solution for angular1? How coul I do the same with ng2?

Comment: What are you using for your registration/login forms?

Comment: 2 dedicated packages for ng2-meteor: barbatus:ng2-meteor-accounts-ui and barbatus:ng2-meteor-accounts

Comment: Since that's just a simple wrapper for accounts-ui, you might be better off using [Meteor.loginWithPassword()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithpassword) which will allow you to redirect in a callback.

Comment: Angular 2.0 is using this instead of $scope.